Cannot push element into union typed array
I have this code
export interface CommonAnimalProps {
    name: string
  
}

export interface DogResponse extends CommonAnimalProps {

}

export interface CatResponse extends CommonAnimalProps {
    color: string,
}

export type AllAnimals = (DogResponse[] | CatResponse[])

export interface AllAnimalsProps {
    height: number | null,
    errorCodes: number[] | null,
    uuid?: string,
    [ANIMALS.dog]?: DogResponse[],
    [ANIMALS.cat]?: CatResponse[],
}

export enum ANIMALS {
    dog = 'dog',
    cat = 'cat'
}

export const transformCalculatedEmissionsResponse = (response: AllAnimalsProps): AllAnimals => {
    const result: AllAnimals = [];
    (Object.values(ANIMALS) as ANIMALS[]).map(animal => {
        const bars = response[animal]
        if (Array.isArray(bars)) {
            bars.map(bar => result.push(bar))
        }
    })
    return result
}

and it fails on this line
bars.map(bar => result.push(bar))


No results
Argument of type 'DogResponse | CatResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CatResponse'.
Property 'color' is missing in type 'DogResponse' but required in type 'CatResponse'.

Why and how solve this?
Here is a Plaground

The problem is, your result is of type AllAnimals which in the end means it's
result: (DogResponse[] | CatResponse[])

ie, it's either a DogResponse[] which can only contain dogs or a CatResponse[] which can only contain cats.
On the other hand, while iterating over your enum values, your bars will be both, once a DogResponse[] and once a CatResponse[] and you are trying to push all values into the same result array, which is not possible.
If you want a mixed array, define your AllAnimals as
type AllAnimals = (DogResponse | CatResponse)[]

which means that result will be
result: (DogResponse | CatResponse)[]

which means, it will be an array, where each element is either a CatResponse or a DogResponse
By the way bars.map(bar => result.push(bar)) doesn't make too much sense. Use
result.push(...bars)

instead.
Generally, it's bad habit to use map for just iterating over values the array. When you don't need the resulting array that map creates use either forEach or a simple for .. of loop
Now that you clarified your problem and preconditions in the comments, you could for instance do it like this
export const transformCalculatedEmissionsResponse = (response: AllAnimalsProps): AllAnimals => {
    for (const animal of Object.values(ANIMALS) as ANIMALS[]) {
        if (Array.isArray(response[animal]))
            return response[animal];
    }

    return [];
}

Ie, iterate over your different types of animals, and once you found the respective value in your response, return it. If none is found just return an empty array (same as you currently already do).

Hm, that is not what I want. I want an array that contains either only DogResponse or CatResponse.

Then why are you trying to push both into the same array?

I understood now what the problem of the compiler is, thanks to your explanation. What I can assure is that response: AllAnimalsProps will only contain either ANIMALS.dog or ANIMALS.cat (at least in the situation shown here). Buut, not sure how to tell this to the compiler.

See the updated answer
